# How to update a message text on telegram api ? (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests, telepot

I'm developing a telegram bot using telepot, I'm trying to ask the user a question for example: What's your name?
Then wait for the user to type the name, and save it in a variable, but this is not a library method, I think.
So I decided to create my own method.
When asking the question "What is your name?" I will go to the telegram api and I will change the text field to empty so in the next function I will use a loop that does not break until the user's last message is different from empty, understand?

I access: https://api.telegram.org/bot/([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKjLe.png)token)getUpdates

and I want to change this session:
**(Change a message send by user)**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPJ8W.png)

"message":{"message_id":1133,"from":{"id":5296812825,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Vinicius","language_code":"pt-br"},"chat" :{"id":5296812825,"first_name":"Vinicius","type":"private"},"date":1652800679,**"text":"Mensagem from User"**}}] }

for

"message":{"message_id":1133,"from":{"id":5296812825,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Vinicius","language_code":"pt-br"},"chat" :{"id":5296812825,"first_name":"Vinicius","type":"private"},"date":1652800679,**"text":"EMPTY"**}}] }

Comment: So you're asking how to change the text of a message send by 'telepot'?

Comment: Don't i want change the text of a message send by user

Comment: Do want to change the text that the user has send?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to edit.

Then I would like to know if it is also possible to delete.

Answer (score 0):

#### No; Bot's can't alter messages send by an user

A Telegram bot can **only** alter/delete his **own** messages.

---

<sub>Luckily, otherwise every message you send could be altered by some random bot, this would lead to insecure behaviour for sure.</sub>

Comment: requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot(TOKENBOT)/getUpdates",{'offset': update_id})
This command delete, i just dont know how to edit.